# Migration/copy of files (mostly pdf, but some jpeg, doc, excel, html ..) from Unix to Azure.

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, bulk-load

Migration/copy of files (mostly pdf, but some jpeg, doc, excel, html ..) from Unix to Azure.

Total size – 9-12 TB
1 in 1,000 files are larger than 25 MB
Biggest file found is 720 MB
Over 30 million documents with thousands of directories
70-90% files are never accessed (no read)
Files will never be written only read

Existing: Files saved in Unix and ref. table in oracle

Proposed: Files in Azure Files and ref. table on SQL Server VM (on azure  which already exists)

Use Azure Data Box (costs around $300 in preview but soon available) to copy files from data center and ship to Azure data center. Is there a more cost effective way to do it?
Copy data box files to Azure File Service storage (on VM) and ref. table in Sql server VM on Azure. These files should be accessible from external salesforce system based on ref table path.
Can we update the folder structure in case there is a need (is there a way to list these file and save the path in a file so that ref. table in sql server be updated?)
Kindly suggest if Blob storage make more sense? any concerns/limitations with file storage.

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to move data from on premises to Azure. Databox is one of them, since you're already aware of it, below are additional options:

**AzCopy**
AzCopy is a command-line utility designed for high-performance copying of data to and from Azure Storage. You can also copy data within a storage account, or between different storage accounts. AzCopy is available on Windows and on Linux.

See Transfer data with the AzCopy Command-Line Utility or Transfer data with AzCopy on Linux to learn more.

**Azure PowerShell:**

Azure PowerShell is a module that provides cmdlets for managing services on Azure. It's a task-based command-line shell and scripting language designed especially for system administration.

**Azure CLI:**

Azure CLI provides a set of open source, cross-platform commands for working with Azure services. Azure CLI is available on Windows, OSX, and Linux.

**[Azure Import/Export:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service)**

Azure Import/Export service is used to securely import large amounts of data to Azure Blob storage and Azure Files by shipping disk drives to an Azure datacenter. This service can also be used to transfer data from Azure Blob storage to disk drives and ship to your on-premises sites. Data from one or more disks can be imported either to Azure Blob storage or Azure Files.

**More info can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-moving-data**